# Android http post to ASP.NET Web API not insert data

Tags: java, android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with android. I want to post a data to ASP.NET Web API. I tried http post by using the below method

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

// adding post params
if (params != null) {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
}

Log.i("serrrrr",""+params);

httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

and my name value pair looks like

```
[attendance={"attendance_id":"0","Usr_Id":"5","Com_Id":"1","date":"12-11-2015","time_in":"04:41:41 pm","time_out":"","location_in":"my address","location_out":"","status_in":"true","status_out":"true","total_time":"","App_id":"1"}]
```

when I tried to post this data to web api I got the following errors

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at WebApplication.Areas.Json.Controllers.AttendancesController.PostAttendance(Attendance attendance)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

How can I resolve this issue? Is there any problem with sending parameters?

Comment: Do you have an access to the server-side code, asp.net web api service that is? Most likely there is a problem with the way you send parameters, because server might expect either something additional, or something in a different format, but it does not do validation properly. It is impossible to figure out without looking at the server side code that throws an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example of

```
[
    attendance={
        "attendance_id":"0",
        "Usr_Id":"5",
        "Com_Id":"1",
        "date":"12-11-2015",
        "time_in":"04:41:41 pm",
        "time_out":"",
        "location_in":"my address",
        "location_out":"",
        "status_in":"true",
        "status_out":"true",
        "total_time":"",
        "App_id":"1"
    }
]
```

Is invalid JSON, because you have a key-value pair inside an array. You can check it on http://jsonlint.com/

So your input/postdata cannot be deserialized, AND the server-side code does not do error handling to catch it (and optionally to return a meaningful error message).

Fix your input.

Comment: my json data is      {
        "attendance_id":"0",
        "Usr_Id":"5",
        "Com_Id":"1",
        "date":"12-11-2015",
        "time_in":"04:41:41 pm",
        "time_out":"",
        "location_in":"my address",
        "location_out":"",
        "status_in":"true",
        "status_out":"true",
        "total_time":"",
        "App_id":"1"
    }

Comment: and "attendance" is my namevalue pair name

Comment: Then remove the [] -s